# mongodb : SyncSourceFeedbackThread] SEVERE: Invalid access at address: 0xa8

Tags: linux, mongodb

last night  out mongodb replset r1  was crashed ,then monit restart it.

this is process stats:

```
mongod    1390     1  0 Aug15 ?        00:39:29 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
root      1967     1  8 Aug15 ?        18:53:29 /usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongod_route.conf
mongod    2127     1  0 Aug15 ?        00:56:07 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod_r2.conf
mongod    2514     1  0 Aug15 ?        01:07:33 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod_config.conf
mongod    2552     1  0 Aug15 ?        00:49:41 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod_arbiter.conf
root      7722 21913  0 03:04 ?        00:00:00 [mongod_r1] <defunct>
mongod    7733     1  0 03:04 ?        00:05:06 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod_r1.conf
root     13964 12745  0 11:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color mongo
```

this is mongodb log:

```
2015-08-25T03:03:53.425+0800 [conn140823]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-08-25T03:03:53.430+0800 [conn140823] replset couldn't find a slave with id 0, not tracking 53d71c612ea2da0bd4c469e6
2015-08-25T03:03:53.432+0800 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] SEVERE: Invalid access at address: 0xa8
2015-08-25T03:03:53.565+0800 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] SEVERE: Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
Backtrace:0x11bd301 0x11bc6de 0x11bc7cf 0x33d060f710 0xeacaf6 0xeb19e8 0x1145332 0x1201c99 0x33d06079d1 0x36818e88fd 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11bd301]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x11bc6de]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x11bc7cf]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x33d060f710]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18SyncSourceFeedback13replHandshakeEv+0xb86) [0xeacaf6]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18SyncSourceFeedback3runEv+0x9b8) [0xeb19e8]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13BackgroundJob7jobBodyEv+0xd2) [0x1145332]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x1201c99]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x33d06079d1]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x36818e88fd]
2015-08-25T03:04:17.172+0800 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7733 port=1201 dbpath=/data/mongo_r1 64-bit host=x2
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.0
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] git version: 1c1c76aeca21c5983dc178920f5052c298db616c
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build14.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-08-25T03:04:17.178+0800 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod_r1.conf", net: { bindIp: "10.165.46.132", port: 1201 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod_r1.pid" },
```

what happened?